# How did this user get a bounty of zero reps?

Tags: bug, reputation, bounty

I was looking at [this users profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense?tab=profile), and I noticed he gained a bounty of 0 reps

[image]

I was wondering how anybody could manage that, but when I looked at the question, it didn't show any signs of a bounty. Is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: Looking at the revision of the question you will see that YCS himself put the bounty on the question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4983915/revisions And he can't get the rep back by choosing his own answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It used to be possible to award a bounty to your own answer, resulting in 0 reputation being awarded.

[This was fixed on 2011-07-07.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/i-just-awarded-myself-a-bounty/97802#97802)